# Spring MVC AND Ajax Request

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I have some problems using ajax with Spring MVC. I want to refresh  only a piece of page using ajax (and get piece of page from controller). So what i'am doing.

```
$.ajax({                                       
  url : '/getCartProducts',
  type : 'GET',
  async: true,
  data : {},
  success : function(data) {  
    //data shoud be rendered jsp with model from the controller  
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown); 
  }
})`
```

This function should to give me view page  from the controller. Here is my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCartProducts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody String ajaxGetProdCart(HttpServletRequest request) {
    LOG.trace("We are in the controller");      
    return "cart"; //this is jsp page
}
```

A trying doing this without @ResponseBody but it's not working. It alerts me error: `Not found`

```
<bean id="validator"
class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basename" value="messages" />
  <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">      
  <property name="messageConverters">
    <list>
      <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Post your servlet context xml as well.  Check your view-resolver configuration. Are you getting the log trace?

Comment: Yeah, that's why i write it, to check if the ajax go to this method. What should i write in view resolver?

Comment: Your cart.jsp must be inside pages folder.You must remove @ResponseBody if you want to serve that jsp page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cart.jsp` must be inside pages folder.You must remove `@ResponseBody` annotation

Comment: Hmm it works without this annotation too. But it return jsp pages with JSTL tags. But i want to have already compiled page.

Comment: this page already in pages folder. Am i doing something wrong, or i don't know something about jstl render.

Comment: Fixed this! I forget to add jstl libs in the top of my jsp page